# syntax to use "hint" in mongo aggregation query in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

HI could any one help me on how to use "hint" in mongo aggregation query, right now i am using below code for querying results.

```
AggregationOptions options = AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(allowDiskUse).build();
        DBCollection dbCollection = db.getPrimativeCollection(colName);           
        Cursor cursor = dbCollection.aggregate(aggregateList, options,
                Config.getInstance().getReadPreferenceEntity(colName));
```

for find query i am able to use like below,

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query, projection).hint(hintName).comment(ThreadLocalAuthInfo.getMongoQueryComment());
```

Hi could anyone help on this?

Comment: Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Database db = DatabaseGroup.getInstance().getDatabase(colName);
        String hint = "dataCenter_1_ownerAccountId_1__id_1";
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("aggregate", colName);
        map.put("pipeline", aggregateList);
        map.put("allowDiskUse", true);
        map.put("cursor", new BasicDBObject());
        if (hint != null) {
            map.put("hint", hint);
        }
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(map);
        BasicDBObject resultDoc = db.databaseForSearch.runCommand(query,
                Config.getInstance().getReadPreferenceEntity(colName), BasicDBObject.class);
        BasicDBObject resultCursor = (BasicDBObject) resultDoc.get("cursor");
        List<BasicDBObject> list = (List<BasicDBObject>) resultCursor.get("firstBatch");
        for (BasicDBObject each : list) {
            lstDBObjects.add(each);
        }
```